# How to view ASP.NET custom HTTP headers in fiddler?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, fiddler

I am setting my custom header by using the following code

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Request.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "test");
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

But I could not view my custom header in Fiddler. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Add custom headers to the Response State (not to the Request):

```
//Request.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "test");
Response.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "test");
```